# response to barachu vs candles, in bringing shabbat in early?

Tags: shabbat, shulchan-aruch, maariv, candle-lighting

I understand how it can be that lighting candles bring in shabbat.

But I don't understand how responding to Barachu(or any part of the davening) can bring in or be used to bring in shabbat.

I can only understand how it can work if it's only the candles that can bring it in.

If it's the candles that bring it in early, and responding to barachu that bring it in early, then the candles have to be done first, because if responding to barachu is done first, then shabbat is in and you can't light the candles.

And if responding to barachu is only ever done after the candles are lit and thus once shabbat is in, then how can responding to barachu bring in shabbat, (shabbat is already in from the candles),

I have a vague recollection once of somebody jumping up and saying not to say Barachu yet. I wonder if they said that because if he said it too early then it'd be before some people had lit the candles and thus it'd cause breaking shabbat. That suggests that it has the power to bring in shabbat but shouldn't be used to do so.

The shulchan Aruch though seems to perhaps suggest it is being used to bring in shabbat.

Shulchan Aruch  261:4

> After responding to Barechu, even though it is still
>   daytime, one may not make an eyruv nor cover over hot foods, for
>   one has thereby already accepted /the holiness of/ Shabbos upon
>   himself. In our times, reciting Mizmor Shir Le- Yom Ha-Shabbos 2* has
>   the same effect as had the response to Barechu /in earlier
>   generations/.

Comment: "Borchu" is the start of Friday night davening. Once you answer Borchu you're essentially saying "it's now Friday night and hence it's Shabbat." Nothing magical or mystical.

Answer (score 2):

See the notes below which show that one can stipulate that lighting the candles will not bring in the Shabbas until later, while saying maarive absolutely does so.

[DinOnline](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/08/19/driving-after-lighting-candles/) says

> Driving After Lighting Candles 19 Av 5771 The Question:
>
> Can a single person light shabbos candles with a bracha with a tanai
>   (condition) that shabbos will be accepted later so that the person can
>   drive to shul?
>
> Answer:
>
> Yes, this is permitted.
>
> Only with regard to women, and with regard to a reagular situation, do
>   we assume that lighting candles implies bringing in Shabbos, and it is
>   therefore forbidden to perform labor after lighting candles.
>
> However, with regard to men, no such assumption is made. Even for
>   women, if a condition is made, the lady in question can light candles
>   with a berachah, and stipulate that she doesn’t mean to bring in
>   Shabbos until later.

[Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/588280/jewish/Is-it-forbidden-to-do-work-after-Shabbat-candle-lighting-time.htm)

> I'd like to add two notes:
>
> a) Though lighting candles doesn't constitute an acceptance of Shabbat
>   (for men, and for women who have in mind not to accept Shabbat at the
>   time), the recitation of the Friday night Shabbat prayers (which also
>   may be done before sunset, see More on Plag Hamincha) does constitute
>   an absolute acceptance of Shabbat.2
>
> b) We are required to "add" on to Shabbat, both when it enters and
>   when it departs. This means that we may not do work until the moment
>   of sunset (or the moment that three stars appear on Saturday night),
>   but we must accept the holiness of Shabbat at least a few moments
>   beforehand.

Thanks to @barlop for finding the following reference

Shulchan Aruch 261:4

> 4 After (28) responding to Barechu, even though (29) it is still
>   daytime, (30) one may not make an eyruv nor cover over hot foods, for
>   one has thereby already accepted /the holiness of/ Shabbos upon
>   himself. In our times, reciting Mizmor Shir Le-Yom Ha- Shabbos 2* has
>   the same effect (31) as had the response to Barechu /in earlier
>   generations/.

Mishnah Brurah on Shulchan Aruch 261:4

> (31) As had the response to Barechu. For, most probably, since mention
>   is made of Shabbos /in this Psalm/, it is the same as an acceptance of
>   /the holiness of/ Shabbos. The M.A. writes: “But now the custom is to
>   say Mizmor Shir, etc., and yet to perform all kinds of labors until
>   Barechu [i.e., if it is still before beyn ha-shemashos]. ” The reason
>   is that originally this was the manner in which they accepted upon
>   themselves this custom /of saying Mizmor Shir, etc./ ; they did not
>   intend it to be an acceptance of /the holiness of/ Shabbos. All this
>   /held true/ at the time of the M.A. But today the custom in all our
>   localities is that as soon as Mizmor Shir is said, the congregation
>   accepts /the holiness of/ Shabbos upon themselves, and it is then
>   forbidden to engage in any work even if there is still much time
>   remaining in the day. [P.Mg. and D.Hach.] The Derech Chochmah writes
>   that the same is true for localities where Lechah Dodi is customarily
>   recited, which concludes “ Bo’i Chalah ” : 8 this constitutes a true
>   acceptance of /the holiness of/ Shabbos. (See To.Sh.)

Comment: so when candles have no condition on them then my question still stands. When Candle lighting(with no condition), then nothing in davening is bringing shabbat in because it's already in once candles are lit. And if the response to barachu was said before candle lighting then shabbat would be broken by the candle lighting.

Comment: Is it then, that the response to barachu has the power to bring in shabbat if it isn't already brought in by sunset or candles. But we'd only want to use that power, in the case of a conditional candle lighting

Comment: @barlop or perhaps in the case where someone doesn't have any candles to light.

Comment: @Daniel ok so only those execptional circumstances. Do shuls make sure that the response to barachu is done some time after shabbat is in, so as to make sure people have lit the candles?

Comment: @barlop As explained in a number of places, Rav Moshe Feinstein states that when Shabbos is brought in early in the summer, the wife is allowed to light closer to the zman. There are other details as to this. As an example, because of Plag Hamincha, one can daven mincha before the earliest candle lighting time (before Plag Hamincha) but starts Kabbolas Shabbas after earliest candle lighting time. There are those who follow the minhag of the wife lighting candles at home at the estimated time the shul would be starting kabbolas shabbos.

Comment: @barlop many shuls bring in Shabbat early. It's the responsibility of those attending to light candles before arriving. (FWIW in many communities, women don't generally attend shul and married men don't light candles. The women light candles at home and have their husbands in mind)

Comment: @sabbahillel to say candle lighting time is a bit ambiguous because it's not clear when dealing with a case where candles are not yet lit, and it's not clear if you mean the time the jewish newspaper or jewish community gives for bringing in shabbat, a time range if somebody might want to bring it in earlier, or what time/time range. And since shabbat can be brought in early, the time one lights candles is a range. Do you mean lechu neranena can only be said after candles are lit? (btw that doesn't take into account a person with no candles)

Comment: @sabbahillel and this association you make between kabbalsh shabbat and bringing shabbat in, makes me ask if in any way it's lechu neranena that brings or is the statement that shabbat is in, before, the response to barachu.

Comment: @barlop The statements say that nowadays, Shabbos is accepted by Mizmor Shir rather than Barchu specifically. THis is because we have put in kabbalas Shabbas just before Barchu. I had seen the specific reference to this, but I did not put it into the post and would have to find it again.

Comment: @sabbahillel I might be able to find a ref to that as i've seen it recently..

Comment: @sabbahillel  Your knowledge/understanding is better than mine, but here is the ref you are looking for (I saw it on davka's mishnah brurah, included a copy/paste  here) http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=A7wBbxQt

Comment: @sabbahillel so that addresses re what brings it in or accepts.. But what about my comment that starts with " to say candle lighting time..."?

Comment: I see.. you write "There are those who follow the minhag of the wife lighting candles at home at the estimated time the shul would be starting kabbolas shabbos." <-- OK so a specific time.. before mizmor shir / before kabbalat shabbat so before lechu neranenah.  So if they don't have candles then tough but nothing's broken and if they do then they follow the time given by the shul to ensure it's before mizmor shir is said.

Comment: So when I heard somebody in the shul say "not yet" for barachu.. and perhaps more correctly they should've said it before mizmor shir leyom hashabbat.. It'd have been because they thought the person leading the service was saying it before so-called candle lighting time, which would be the latest time anybody in that community should be lighting candles.

Comment: I see from a shul leaflet that the candle lighting time from when the service starts(apparently not before  - according to what this leaflet says), To when the community bring shabbat in.

Comment: @Daniel You write "It's the responsibility of those attending to light candles before arriving."  <-- If candles are lit before the man leaves or before the man arrives to shul (and the person is on time for shul like 1min before the service starts), then technically they'd be lit before the service starts.  This shul leaflet I have says service starts x time, candle lighting x time, and not before.

Comment: @barlop that shul leaflet probably assumes the wives are lighting candles at home while the husbands are at shul

Comment: @Daniel For sure but you were saying they should light it before the man arrives(so before the service starts). The leaflet says not to light it before the service starts.  So who's right?/i'm curious the basis for each. Why did you say before arriving? Does your wife or the wives you know, (ever) light it before the man leaves / before he arrives?

Comment: @barlop When I said it's the responsibility of those attending to light before arriving, I meant in the case where the person going to shul is lighting candles. Usually what happens is the wife stays home and lights some time after the husband has already left.

Comment: @Daniel oh I see.. so it must be that they can be lit before the service starts (otherwise men living alone wouldn't be able to light them). So it must be that they can be lit before the service starts but maybe the closer to mizmor shir, the better.. or the closer to the service starting, the better.